# Python project structure : "Unresolved reference"

Tags: python, pycharm

I structured my python project like that:

```
- project/
+- package/
 +- db/
  +- __init__.py
  +- mydb.py
+- tests/
 +- context.py
 +- mytest.py
+- file.py
```

In `project/package/db/__init__.py` I declared mydb as :

```
from package.db import mydb
```

With this declaration, I can use `mydb` functions in `file.py`, using:

```
import package.db as db

db.mydb.myfunction()
```

But I would like to use this function in `project/tests` directory as well. So, I added a `project/tests/context.py` file with:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import package.db as db
```

And in `mytest.py` :

```
from context import db

db.mydb.myfunction()
```

It's working well.

But PyChar says that :

- `import package.db as db` (in context.py) is an unused import statement
- `from context import db` (in mytest.py) contains unresolved (context) reference

Is there a way to improve this project structure in order to get rid of those warning & errors ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have an `__init__.py` file in your `package` and `tests` folders; meaning it's not a python package. - If you want them to be.
2. You're not using the import statement properly; also, you're not using the import in the `context.py` file, so in order to fix it, you'll need to remove the line.
3. I suggest reading [more here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) about packages; which will give you more insight into what you should put inside your `__init__.py` files.

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

The structure I would use:

```
- package_name
   - db
     - __init__.py
     - my_db.py
   - tests
     - __init__.py
     - my_test.py
   - __init__.py
```

The only code you need to add is in the `my_db.py` file:

```
def my_function():
    return 1
```

and in your `my_test.py` file you'll have:

```
from package.db import mydb

mydb.my_function()
```

That's all you need; in regards to altering imports through the `__init__.py` file, look into `__all__` if you really have to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it is very clear ! I corrected my structure using your recommandation and it works well. Do I still need to maintain the imports in db/__init__.py file (second code block in my question) ?

Comment: I personally like to keep my `__init__.py` files as clean as possibly; the only thing I put there are any manipulation of the imports (using `__all__` - read more about it, it's quite interesting..) - so no, I don't think you need to maintain imports in the `__init__.py` file. - In other words; you can manipulate what `from your_library import *` will import for the user; which is specified using the `__all__` variable in the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: If I launch my_function from outside package or in package, it works. But if I launch `my_test.py`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'`. Any idea why ? I think that was the reason for using a "context" file

Comment: OK, found it. I need to call using `python -m package.tests.my_test` with `.` and no ` /` and without `.py` extension